# Нужна помощь с регуляркой js

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Добрый день!
Помогите правильно составить регулярное выражение для такого примера:

```
var tel1 = '+7 (999) 999-99-99' ;
var tel2 = '+7 (   )    -  -  ' ;
var myRe = <регулярное_выражение> ;

if(myRe.test(tel1)) alert('Проверка tel1 пройдена') ;
else alert('Проверка tel1 не пройдена') ;
if(myRe.test(tel2)) alert('Проверка tel2 пройдена') ;
else alert('Проверка tel2 не пройдена') ;
```

Правильный вариант телефона tel1 (+7 (999) 999-99-99)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<регулярное_выражение> = +7\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

Comment: тогда уж +7\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}

Comment: @barber - Очепятался, прошу прощения =)